# Using a custom value text formatter with Microsoft ILogger

Tags: c#, logging, microsoft-extensions-logging

I've currently got some code that looks like this:

```cs
_logger.LogInformation("Found a problem {Problem}", Format(problemDetails));
```

where Format converts ProblemDetails to a string.

I would like to register a handler within the logging framework to explain how this type should be serialized to string so that I could type

```cs
_logger.LogInformation("Found a problem {Problem}", problemDetails);
```

and not just get the result of calling `.ToString()`. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not override ToString in the class?

Comment: Sometimes a good answer, not such a great one if the object is in a third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `@` before the `Problem`. The `problemDetails` is written as Json:[Structured logging](https://habr.com/en/post/591171/)

```
_logger.LogInformation("Found a problem {@Problem}", problemDetails);
```

Comment: I guess then the question becomes: how to you employ a JsonConverter in that context?